# Grep Command on a Variable to get desired output

Tags: bash, grep

`cat /etc/os-release | grep -m 1 NAME`

Following is the output

`NAME="Ubuntu"`

I only want the string as a my output how to do it?

Comment: Another approach: `source /etc/os-release; echo "$NAME"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '(?<=^NAME=").*(?=")' /etc/os-release
```

Output:

```
Ubuntu
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)